# Function does not exist when calling flash method from JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have a simple flash socket that I use to connect to IRC servers. It has an `open`, `close`, and `send` method made available to JS through `ExternalInterface`, for opening connections, closing connections, and sending messages respectively. The socket calls `IRC.io.receive` in JS whenever it gets a message, which is parsed by JS into something useful.

Unfortunately, whenever any of the flash methods are called from JS, they return a "__ is not a function" error.

Here's the (watered down) AS, where IRC is the document class:

```
public class IRC extends MovieClip {
    public static function open(url:String, port:int) {/* code */}
    public static function close(port:int) {/* code */}
    public static function send(port:int, message:String) {/* code */}

    public function IRC() {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback('send', IRC.send);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback('open', IRC.open);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback('close', IRC.close);
    }
}
```

And HTML/JS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.IRC = {
                io: {}
            };
            IRC.io.receive = function(message) {/* code */}
            IRC.io.send = function(port, str) {
                document.getElementById('socket').send(port, str);
            }
            IRC.io.open = function(url, port) {
                document.getElementById('socket').open(url, port);
            }
            IRC.io.close = function(port) {
                document.getElementById('socket').close(port);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ui -->
        <embed src="socket.swf" quality="high" allowscriptsaccess="always" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" style="display:none;">
    </body>
<html>
```

Any call to any of the functions registered with `ExternalInterface` throws a "function does not exist" exception. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try signalling from your swf when it's ready to receive calls.

For example, in your ActionScript:

```
ExternalInterface.call('initIRQ');
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
function initIRQ() {
    //Begin communication with swf
}
```

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work either - flash doesn't seem to be able to call JS. Is it possible, then, that the class isn't working correctly?

Comment: Check if `ExternalInterface` is available: 
`if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call('initIRQ');
} else {
    trace("ExternalInterface unavailable");
}`
If not, you could try waiting until the page is fully loaded (if you're not doing this already) before trying to access the functions in the swf.

Comment: That somehow fixed it - it works now. Thanks for your help (: